# Disable and enable radiobuttons from another radiobutton in PyQt4 Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qradiobutton

I have 3 radiobutton groups in forms of Yes or No. I want to disable the last 2 radiobutton groups if the first radiobutton is "No" and enable them when the first radiobutton is "Yes". I can make the enabled or disabled by default but toggling Yes/No from the first group doesn't change the result in the second and third group.

Here is a summary of my code:

```
self.yes_radioButtonGroup1 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
self.yes_radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup1"))
self.no_radioButtonGroup1 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
self.no_radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup1"))
self.radioButtonGroup1= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
self.radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup1"))
self.radioButtonGroup1.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup1)
self.radioButtonGroup1.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup1)

self.yes_radioButtonGroup2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
self.yes_radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup2"))
self.no_radioButtonGroup2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
self.no_radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup2"))
self.radioButtonGroup2= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
self.radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup2"))
self.radioButtonGroup2.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup1)
self.radioButtonGroup2.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup1)

self.yes_radioButtonGroup3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
self.yes_radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup3"))
self.no_radioButtonGroup3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
self.no_radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup3"))
self.radioButtonGroup3= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
self.radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup3"))
self.radioButtonGroup3.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup3)
self.radioButtonGroup3.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup3)


if self.yes_radioButtonGroup1.isChecked() == True:
        self.yes_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(True)
        self.no_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(True)
        self.yes_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(True)
        self.no_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(True)

elif self.no_radioButtonGroup1.isChecked() == True:
        self.yes_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(False)
        self.no_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(False)
        self.yes_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(False)
        self.no_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(False)
```

I was wondering if anybody knows how to dynamically enable or disable the last two radiobutton group when values from the first radiobutton changes?

Comment: Are the radio button exclusive? Are they in a QGroupBox?

Comment: They are exclusive, at least one (either Yes or No) should be selected.
each pair are in a different QButtonGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the buttons are exclusive enough to monitor one of them, so the appropriate signal is `toggled()` that sends the information if the button is checked or not.

```
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup1 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup1"))
    self.no_radioButtonGroup1 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.no_radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup1"))
    self.radioButtonGroup1= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
    self.radioButtonGroup1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup1"))
    self.radioButtonGroup1.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup1)
    self.radioButtonGroup1.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup1)

    self.yes_radioButtonGroup2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup2"))
    self.no_radioButtonGroup2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.no_radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup2"))
    self.radioButtonGroup2= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
    self.radioButtonGroup2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup2"))
    self.radioButtonGroup2.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup1)
    self.radioButtonGroup2.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup1)

    self.yes_radioButtonGroup3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)      
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yes_radioButtonGroup3"))
    self.no_radioButtonGroup3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.no_radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("no_radioButtonGroup3"))
    self.radioButtonGroup3= QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)   
    self.radioButtonGroup3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonGroup3"))
    self.radioButtonGroup3.addButton(self.yes_radioButtonGroup3)
    self.radioButtonGroup3.addButton(self.no_radioButtonGroup3)

    self.yes_radioButtonGroup1.toggled(self.on_yes_checked)
    # set initial state
    self.on_yes_checked(self.yes_radioButtonGroup1.isChecked())

def on_yes_checked(self, checked):
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(checked)
    self.no_radioButtonGroup2.setEnabled(checked)
    self.yes_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(checked)
    self.no_radioButtonGroup3.setEnabled(checked)
```

Comment: `QButtonGroup()` has no `setEnabled()` method in Pyside2. How can I enable/disable all buttons in a group, other than iterating over all buttons.