# setChecked radiobutton of another group pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have 2 radiobuttons created (inside a QMainWindow class) like:

```
    def dtype_radiobuttons(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        rb1 = QRadioButton("complex")
        rb1.toggled.connect(lambda: self.update_image("dtype", rb1.text()))


        self.real_dtype_rb = QRadioButton("real", self)
        self.real_dtype_rb.toggled.connect(lambda: self.update_image("dtype", self.real_dtype_rb.text()))

        self.btngroup.append(QButtonGroup())
        self.btngroup[-1].addButton(self.real_dtype_rb)
        self.btngroup[-1].addButton(rb1)

        rb1.setChecked(True)
        layout.addWidget(rb1)
        layout.addWidget(self.real_dtype_rb)
        layout.addStretch()

        return layout

    def library_radiobutton(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cvnn_library_rb = QRadioButton("cvnn", self)
        self.cvnn_library_rb.toggled.connect(lambda: self.update_image("library", self.cvnn_library_rb.text()))

        rb2 = QRadioButton("tensorflow", self)
        rb2.toggled.connect(lambda: self.update_image("library", rb2.text()))

        self.btngroup.append(QButtonGroup())
        self.btngroup[-1].addButton(rb2)
        self.btngroup[-1].addButton(self.cvnn_library_rb)

        self.cvnn_library_rb.setChecked(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.cvnn_library_rb)
        layout.addWidget(rb2)
        layout.addStretch()

        return layout
```

I want to make it **impossible** to select the `complex` option of the dtype radiobuttons group and `tensorflow` radiobutton of the library radiobuttons. Leaving 3 out of the 4 possible combinations. So if I select `complex` and library was `tensorflow`, I want to automatically change the library to `cvnn`. I tried to implement it like this:

```
    def update_image(self, key, value):
        if value == "complex":
            if hasattr(self, 'cvnn_library_rb'):    # It wont exists if I still didnt create the radiobutton.
                self.cvnn_library_rb.setChecked(True)   # Set library cvnn
        elif value == "tensorflow":
            if hasattr(self, 'real_dtype_rb'):
                self.real_dtype_rb.setChecked(True)   # Set real dtype
        ... Do the other stuff I need to do.
```

The weird thing is that it actually works in the sense that, for example, if I am on `complex` activated and select `tensorflow`, the radiobutton changes to `real` (what I want!) but `tensorflow` does not get selected! I need to select it again as if making `self.real_dtype_rb.setChecked(True)` cancels the selection of the radiobutton I clicked on. (Very weird if you ask me).

---

- The `hasattr` is used because depending on the order I call the
  functions, there are some radiobuttons that will be created before
  the other, so it might not exist.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929668/disable-and-enable-radiobuttons-from-another-radiobutton-in-pyqt4-python)
  is an option I am considering but it's disabling the radiobutton
  group instead of changing their state (not what I prefer).

Comment: you coulse use `self.cvnn_library_rb = None` at start and then you don't need `hasattr(self, 'cvnn_library_rb')` but `if self.cvnn_library_rb:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal `toggled` is triggered whenever you change the state of your radio buttons. So, it will be triggered when you call `setChecked` (once for the radio button you toggle and once for the other you untoggle) and `update_image` is called is the *wrong* case.

You have to check the state of the radio button and call `update_image` only if the radio button is toggled:

```
rb2.toggled.connect(lambda state: state and self.update_image("library", rb2.text(), state))
```